# How can i left-align a whole row with numbers

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a listbox full of numbers. I am exporting these values to excel but I Want to left align the the numbers in each cell. Every time I try this my program crashes

I tried to add an extra row of code in my for loop to try to align it left but it crashes it gives the following error:

> Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

This is what I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox3.Items.Count; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[i + 21, 1] = listBox3.Items[i].ToString();
    worksheet.Cells[21, i].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
}
```

but it crashes. What I want is that all the values align left.

Comment: shouldn't it be `worksheet.Cells[i + 21, 1].HorizontalAlignment`?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using different indices for `worksheet.Cells` inside the loop? Shouldn't they be the same? Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox3.Items.Count; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[i + 21, 1] = listBox3.Items[i].ToString();
    worksheet.Cells[i + 21, 1].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
}
```